# ul,ul li from less to CSS

Tags: css, syntax, less

I've been searching for this for a bit.
I am trying to achieve this in css from less

```
ul,ul li{ 
display:inline-block; 
}
```

The less I am using is this:

```
ul,ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Problem is, that if I try to add extra properties to the li or it's children the above LESS is not good, as it outputs like so:

LESS

```
 ul,ul li{
     display:inline-block;
     li{ 
      float:left;    
     }
 }
```

CSS

```
ul,
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li,
ul li li {
  float: left;
}
```

How can I achieve this:

```
ul,
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and nothing else from less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
ul {
    &, li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

which will generate the following CSS:

```
ul,
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

If you *already* have a declaration for `ul`:

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You can obtain the same effect using `extend`:

```
ul {
    li:extend(ul) {}
}
```

or the same result in one block without the `&` with `extend`:

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  li:extend(ul) {}
}
```

Comment: You are correct! Thank you! I knew I was missing something easy!

Comment: hmm... the :extend part did not give the same effect
`ul{`
    `li:extend(li){`
        `display:block;`
    `}`
`}`
`
returns
`ul li {`
  `display: block;`
`}`
`

Comment: Yes. You are right. It should have been *if you already have a declaration for `ul`*